# latex hyperref package warning

Tags: hyperref, compiling, warnings

> `Lecture Note.tex:1898: Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing \hbox' on input line 1898.
>   Lecture Note.tex:1898: Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing\z@' on input line 1898.
>   Lecture Note.tex:1898: Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing`\hss' on input line 1898.`

What is this error message meaning? It does not make critical error, but makes an warning on latex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us what’s going on in lines 1895 to 1890 of `LectureNote.tex`. Please also tell us with which options you loaded `hyperref`.

Answer (score 2):

Each of these messages tells that code line 1898 of "Lecture Note.tex" contains some code whose expansion and processing by the TeX-engine/by the LaTeX-compiler yields that in a place, where a PDF-string is expected, a token is found which does not fit into a PDF-string. Each of these messages also tells you that the token in question was removed from what is to be the PDF-string in question.

A PDF-string is a string/a sequence of characters which is to be "understood"/interpreted/processed/rendered by the PDF-viewing program when displaying the .pdf-file (which beforehand was created by means of the TeX-engine/by means of the LaTeX-compiler).

[PDF standards](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive.html) say that PDF-strings (strings of type "text string type") can be encoded either in an encoding whose name is PDFDocEncoding or can be encoded in Unicode (UTF-16BE = UTF-16 Big Endian).

The hyperref package converts things that are to be PDF-strings from the TeX-engine's internal character encoding to PDFDocEncoding or UTF-16BE automatically.

The phrase "PDFDocEncoding" in the warning indicates that (due to not using hyperref's package option `unicode`) the hyperref package currently is set up to encode PDF-strings in PDFDocEncoding. (If hyperref is loaded with the option `unicode`, then PDF-strings will be encoded in UTF-16BE.)

TeX-code which is to form the textual phrase of a bookmark in the .pdf-file should (after expansion) yield a sequence of character tokens which

1. can be converted from the TeX-engine's internal character encoding to the encoding chosen for PDF-strings.
2. forms something that can be understood/interpreted/processed/rendered by the PDF-viewing program (e.g. Adobe Acrobat) for displaying the bookmark-phrase in a separate area of the window where the .pdf-file in question is displayed.

If in the stage where the TeX-engine/the LaTeX-compiler is running and processing the .tex-sourcecode for producing the .pdf-file a set of tokens which is to form the textual phrase of such a bookmark contains, e.g., the non-expandable primitive token `\hbox`, then that is a problem because

- on the one hand the TeX control sequence token `\hbox` is not a character which can be converted from the TeX-engine's internal character-encoding to the encoding chosen for PDF-strings.
- on the other hand taking `\hbox` literally and converting the literal sequence would deliver the character-sequence `\`, `h`, `b`, `o`, `x` as a part of the PDF-string while when viewing the .pdf-file one doesn't want to see the letter-sequence  `h`, `b`, `o`, `x` as a part of the bookmark's textual phrase (, which would be the case because the PDF-viewing-program does—unlike the LaTeX-compiler—not take the sequence `\`, `h`, `b`, `o`, `x` for a control-sequence but takes `\` for the directive to "escape" the following character and thus displays the `h` and also the sequence `b`, `o`, `x` literally).

When using hyperref while creating .pdf-files, then (beneath other things) bookmarks are created automatically. Hereby the textual phrases of the bookmarks are obtained from the arguments of sectioning-commands like `\chapter` or `\section`.  If these arguments (after expansion) contain (non-character-)tokens whose conversion from the TeX-engine's internal character encoding to the encoding chosen for PDF-strings causes problems and whose literal representation will, when occuring in a textual phrase of a bookmark, not be "understood"/interpreted/processed/rendered by a PDF-viewing program, but (erroneously) will be displayed literally, then you get warning messages like the ones encountered by you.

That's why the hyperref package brings along the `\texorpdfstring`-mechanism:

hyperref's macro `\texorpdfstring{⟨TeX string⟩}{⟨PDF string⟩}` processes two arguments:

The first argument denotes a set of tokens to be used in situations where things only need to be "understood"/interpreted/processed by the TeX-engine/by the LaTeX-compiler.
The second argument denotes a set of tokens to be used in situations where things will be converted to the encoding chosen for PDF-Strings (PDFDocEncoding/UTF-16BE) as things (after creating the .pdf-file) need to be "understood"/interpreted/processed/rendered by the PDF-viewing-program.

Thus you can, e.g., do something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{%
  A section about 
  \protect\texorpdfstring{\hbox{\protect\texttt{typewriter}}}{typewriter} 
  %\hbox{\protect\texttt{typewriter}} %<-This way you get a warning which
                     %  informs about the removal of the token  \hbox
                     %  from the PDF-string which LaTeX/hyperref is about
                     %  to create/prepare for the bookmark because with
                     %  the phrase "\hbox{...}"
                     %  - for one thing the token  \hbox  is not a
                     %    character which can be converted to the encoding
                     %    chosen for PDF-strings
                     %  - for another thing having the phrase "hbox"
                     %    literally in the text of the bookmark seems
                     %    undesired.
                     %  "\texttt" would cause similar problems but the
                     %  author of hyperref already took that into account
                     %  and "\texttt" is removed silently by hyperref
                     %  while examining things that are to be transformed
                     %  into PDF-strings.)
  font%
}%
Some text.
\end{document}
```

*A PDF-viewing program might display the .pdf-file resulting from compiling the example above like this:*

[image]

Due to `\texorpdfstring`'s first argument the phrase "typewriter" will be put into a `\hbox` and will be written in typewriter-font within the text of the document.
Due to `\texorpdfstring`'s second argument you just have the plain phrase "typewriter" within the bookmarks, without control-sequences like `\hbox` or `\texttt` which are not "understood" (and therefore would be displayed literally) by the PDF-viewing-program which processes bookmark-phrases for displaying bookmarks.

More information about `\texorpdfstring` and about PDF-strings (and warnings in case things are not suitable for PDF-strings) can be found in [section 4.1.2 Replacement Macros of the manual of the hyperref package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf#subsubsection.4.1.2) and in [section 6 Dealing with Pdf strings of the commented source code of the hyperref package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/hyperref.pdf#section.6).